# xml attributes not being detected

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I'm having some trouble with my c# application. It's only able to get the attributes of the first node and then it can't get the following node's attributes.

The XML is in this format..

```
<ALLPRODUCTS>
  <PRODUCT ITEM="1">
     <QUANTITY>5</QUANTITY>
  </PRODUCT>
  <PRODUCT ITEM="2">
     <QUANTITY>6</QUANTITY>
  </PRODUCT>....
```

The application gets the first product number as 1 and it has a quantity of 5... but after that it just gives the quantities and says the item number is null. Here is the code im using...

```
 while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Name.Equals("PRODUCT"))
            {
                String id;
                String qty;                

                try
                {

                    id = reader.GetAttribute("ITEM");
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("QUANTITY");
                    qty = reader.ReadInnerXml();

                    if (qty.Equals("0"))
                    {
                        oos++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        inStock++;
                    }

                    status.Refresh();
                    stockLevelList.Add(id, qty);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, e.Source, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

            }
```

Can anyone suggest why the products after the first one are getting null as id?

Comment: Unless your XML is HUGE (ie larger than say 25 Mb), you're likely better off using DOM methods, like XmlDocument and SelectNodes for this kind operation.

Comment: I think you want to do `reader.MoveToNextAttribute()` and then check the name to see if it is `ITEM`. If it is then you can call `reader.Value` to get it. For this though, I would probably just use XML serialization with some POCOs instead of fighting with the XML Reader. It can be quite the PITA to develop against.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for the comments... TyCobb I tried your solution but it doesnt seem to make a difference. I have got each iteration printing out the "hasAttributes" evaluation but after the first one they are all saying false. Everything seems to be there except the attributes :/

Comment: You should visit these links:

 http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-read-xml.htm
 http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlreader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking if the reader is at the beginning of the element. Your code is blowing up because it is trying to process based on the end element of `PRODUCT`.

Add this check just after the `if` statement where it is checking for "PRODUCT".

```
if (reader.Name.Equals("PRODUCT"))
{
    if (!reader.IsStartElement())
        continue;

    // Your normal processing code here.
}
```

This is what makes using the `XmlReader` somewhat of a pain. It traverses every single element which means you need to pay attention to where it could be. The first time through, it is at the Start Element. You process and everything is good, but then it reaches the `</PRODUCT>` element which is still named `"PRODUCT"` and that's where it falls apart.

Below is the order based on your code of moving the `reader` forward.

- `reader.Read()` moves to the first element: `ALLPRODUCTS`
- Not what you were looking for so `reader.Read()` again and it finds node type `Whitespace` because there is no inner text.
- `reader.Read()` moved to `PRODUCT`
- You get an attribute and then tell it to read to `QUANTITY`. (Note you cannot go back. Order matters)
- `reader.Read()` moves to the next element `PRODUCT`. This is not `<PRODUCT>`. It is `</PRODUCT>`.
- Your code now begins most of the above process again, but fails because it was not on `<PRODUCT>`

EDIT: Also becareful with `XmlReader`. The XML doesn't necessarily have to be valid in order for `XmlReader` to work up to a certain point. It will only throw an error once it reaches an issue and you may have already processed several hundred nodes at that point.

Comment: @FearghalConn I found the issue immediately by moving the mouse over `reader` to check the values after every `Read()`. It said "EndElement". The debugger is your friend  ;)